# row selected in popover should be added to uitablewview?

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, popover

The **popover** appears when the user selects the first row from the table?

When the user selects any row from the popover the cell should be added to the corresponding table i.e the table from which the popover is presented? how can i do this?

```
third = nil;
self.colorPickerPopover = nil;
UITableViewCell *cell= [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
CGRect rect=CGRectMake(cell.bounds.origin.x+300, cell.bounds.origin.y+10, 10, 10);
if (indexPath.section ==0) {
    if (indexPath.row == 0 ) {
        if (third == nil) {
            third  = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
            UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:third];
            self.colorPickerPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller] ;
            [colorPickerPopover setDelegate:self];
            [self.colorPickerPopover presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:cell permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
            UIBarButtonItem *closeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(cancelClicked)];
            [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
            third.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = closeButton;
            UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(doneClicked)];
            [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
            third.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
        }
```

Comment: have you got the answer?

Comment: i knew the logic i think i need to use a singleton..

Answer (score 0):

ok for getting this one try like this  when your popover dismisses at that time reload your tableview with new array of elements.

```
EDIT:
```

take an array which is used for displaying the data on tableview and whenever you are dismissing pop overview at that time add selected elements in to that tableview arrayan then reload your tableview with new tableview array.

Comment: on done button clicked i want all the selected rows to be added to the uitableview??

Comment: once check my edited answer just i'm giving overview for getting logic.@user2042282